# "systemctl stop" does not stop service

Tags: mongodb, suse, systemctl, sles

This is in SLES 12

I tried searching for this and did not see any other questions about it. When trying to stop the mongodb service, I type:

`sudo systemctl stop mongod.service`

This on its own does not return any errors, it runs just fine, but then when I run:

`sudo systemctl status mongod.service`

I get:

```
mongod.service - mongodb database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-02-06 08:22:04 EST; 19min ago
 Main PID: 4877 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 06 08:22:04 riskdb mongod[4877]: about to fork child process, waiting u...s.
Feb 06 08:22:04 riskdb mongod[4877]: forked process: 4879
Feb 06 08:22:04 riskdb mongod[4877]: ERROR: child process failed, exited wi... 1
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

If anyone has any ideas that would be fantastic, if you need more information from me please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to identify the solution for this?